# Lengthen Javafx Sliders in GridPane

Tags: javafx, slider

Whatever I try, the slider refuses to lengthen/stretch horizontally. My theory is that the GridPane cell sizes are overriding the slider's x coordinate. Any solutions?

here's my entire class:

```
public class MoodMeter extends GridPane {

public MoodMeter() {
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
    grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setVgap(10);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));

    Slider slider = new Slider(-100, 100, 0);
    slider.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
    slider.setMaxWidth(100);
    slider.setBlockIncrement(100);
    setHgrow(slider, Priority.ALWAYS);
    grid.add(slider, 1, 0);

    Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 700, 100);

    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setTitle("Diary Mood Meter");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.show();
    Rectangle2D desktop = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
    stage.setY(((desktop.getMaxY() + desktop.getMinY()) / 2) + 200);
}
}
```

And this is the result:
(not enough population)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NbJ2.png

---

Solved.
Changed 
        slider.setMaxWidth(100);
        slider.setBlockIncrement(100);
to

```
    slider.setMaxWidth(1000);
    slider.setBlockIncrement(1000);
```

Comment: If you set the max width to 100, it is not going to grow to more than 100 pixels wide no matter what you do with the `GridPane`.

Comment: It doesn't really make any sense to set the `blockIncrement` to a value that is bigger than the range of the slider value. You seem to be confused between the physical size of the slider and the data it is representing. Perhaps it would help to read the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html) again.

Comment: @James_D Don't worry I know. I was using big numbers to see an obvious difference. :) I sized it correctly the way I wanted now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: But `blockIncrement` has absolutely nothing to do with the size (or appearance). That was my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the rest of your GridPane code setup, there are several ways to achieve that:

- set `slider.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE)`
- add [ColumnConstraints](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/ColumnConstraints.html) for horizontal resizing to the GridPane
- [set the Hgrow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setHgrow-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.scene.layout.Priority-) of your slider accordingly.

Comment: I Added the MaxWidth and the HGrow and all that did was make the slider go to the left side of the window rather than resize it. :/

Comment: If none of the posted solutions work for you, please update your question to include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `hgrow` property for the slider to `ALWAYS`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SliderInGridPane extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        root.add(new Label("Value:"), 0, 0);
        Slider slider = new Slider(0, 100, 50);
        GridPane.setHgrow(slider, Priority.ALWAYS);
        root.add(slider, 1, 0);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 250, 75));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```